# Getting data out of JSON array list based on a chosen number

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to process an arraylist that comes from another object but I want it to only make a new JSON array containing student number (which should be the same number as lStudentZelf) & aanwezigheid.

```
{
    "klas": "V1A",
    "docent": "Buddha",
    "les": "AUI",
    "studenten": [{
            "studentnummer": 12312591,
            "status": "afwezig"
        },
        {
            "studentnummer": 1214531,
            "status": "aanwezig"
        },
        {
            "studentnummer": 1214531,
            "status": "aanwezig"
        }
    ]
}
```

(this is how the arraylist looks like, I want it to output only the results of studentnumber 1214531 and keep track of how many times this studentnumber has had the status aanwezig.)

I've tried the code below and aswell tried parsing it on several other ways without avail.

```
private void ophalen(Conversation conversation) {
    JsonObject lJsonObjectIn = (JsonObject) conversation.getRequestBodyAsJSON();
    String lGebruikersnaam = lJsonObjectIn.getString("username");
    Student lStudentZelf = informatieSysteem.getStudent(lGebruikersnaam);
    int lNummerZelf = lStudentZelf.getStudentNummer(); //lNummerZelf will be the number that needs to be the same as the 'studentennummer' in the list.
    ArrayList<Statistiek> Test2 = Statistiek.getStatistieken();

    JsonArrayBuilder lJsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    for (Statistiek s : Test2) {
    JsonObjectBuilder lJsonObjectBuilder= Json.createObjectBuilder();
    lJsonObjectBuilder.add("aanwezig", aanwezig);
    lJsonObjectBuilder.add("afwezig", afwezig);
    lJsonObjectBuilder.add("geoorloofd", gafwezig);
    lJsonObjectBuilder.add("vak", vak);
    lJsonArrayBuilder.add(lJsonObjectBuilder);
    }
    String lJsonOutStr = lJsonArrayBuilder.build().toString();
    conversation.sendJSONMessage(lJsonOutStr);
}
```

}

In the end I want that it only reads the studentnummer and status part, and keeps track of how many times a specific status appeared (like aanwezig 2x for studentnummer 1214531) belonging to a chosen studentnummer.

Comment: Javascript  `!==` Java

Comment: Have you tried, to create a pojo out of the json and act on the pojo?